# save updated input type="date" to date-picker-field

Tags: php, html

Hello i want to add on a page an datepicker but it updates not correctly. It displays the updated date on the side of the field instead in the field. 
I have searched solution but have not found any useful Threads. Mabe one of you can help me. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    function datez(){
        $event_date_display_save=get_option('event_date_scripts','none'); 
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Update Scripts</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">            
        <label>Event-Datum:
            <input type="date" id="event_date_id" name="event_date_nametag">
            <?php print $event_date_display_save;?>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_scripts_update" class="button button-primary" value="UPDATE">
    </form>
</div>
<?php }
```

how it looks: [https://imgur.com/a/u2jYT39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkwJ3.png)
how i want it is that the updated date should be saved on the date.

Comment: The date should be in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>Event-Datum:</label><input type="date" id="event_date_id" name="event_date_nametag" value="<?php print $event_date_display_save;?>">
```

You placed everything inside the label

Answer (score 0):

As @Popescu Ion already said, you placed it inside the `<label>` tag. Nevertheless you might wanna paste it into the `value` property.

Comment: Okay @Popescu Ion just updated the code and added value aswell

Comment: Thank you for the answer too.